# Using files as arguments for a Java program in the terminal

Tags: java, file, terminal

```
java someJavaProgram fsa.fsa <test.txt
```

That, apparently, is a legitimate command to take with two files as arguments for a Java program in the terminal - one to read in, and then the other (and I think the idea is that it prints the output to the terminal directly). someJavaProgram, fsa.fsa and test.txt are all files in the same directory (being someProject/src, and someJavaProgram in the default package).

However, the response I am given in the terminal just says:

```
FSA file not found - please scan in the appropriate file.
Testing file not found, please scan in the new relevant file.
```

My question is two-fold:

- What is this command and what is it for?
- Does it need refining or modifying or is it the program that needs improvement?

I should note that I wrote the code in Eclipse, where I simply hardcoded filepaths into the program. I'm not sure if that affects anything but it's related.

EDIT: The filepaths and related code are as follows:

```
private static final String FILE_PATH = "src/test.txt";
private static final String FSA_PATH = "src/fsa1.fsa";
...
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    interpretAutomaton();
    testAutomaton();
}
...
interpretAutomaton() {
...
Scanner fsaScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FSA_PATH)));
...
testAutomaton() {
...
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILE_PATH)));
```

*Both are surrounded by try/catch blocks - which clearly work!

Thanks to anyone who can help clarify on the matter!

Comment: Can you post the code where you read the files in; this will help with diagnosis. Although if you hard-coded the file names in your code then the command line may be being ignored. Further, the second file is being made available on the standard input - this is the effect of the `<`.

Comment: Tip noted. Could you elaborate on what you mean re "made available on the standard input"?

Comment: Standard input is what you read from `System.in`.

Comment: Can you show us your `main(String[] args)` method?  This is where the command line arguments are available.

Comment: OK, your code is using the hard-coded file names defined by `FILE_PATH ` and `FSA_PATH` and ignoring the command line arguments. I'm guessing the responses you see on the terminal are from your code for when it cannot find either file? The cause could be these files are not available at those paths relative to the directory you are running the command from.

Comment: "Made available on the standard input" is an example of [redirection](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html). In your case you are redirecting (or trying to) the contents of `test.txt` to the standard input of your program. As it's a java program it would be available on `System.in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments so far, to answer your actual questions:

1) The command has four elements:

- `java` - execute the java program
- `someJavaProgram` - the name of the Java class to execute
- `fsa.fsa` - the first argument to the java program, accessible via `argv[]`
- `<test.txt` - standard input redirection, the contents of the file will be available on the program's standard input, ie. `System.in`

The net effect is to run your Java program with one argument and one file's contents on the standard input.

2) Both the command line and the program look like they need to change:

- change the command line to:

  java someJavaProgram fsa.fsa test.txt

That is, remove the `<`. You will also need to check the paths to the files are correct. This command line assume you are in the same directory as the files when you execute it.

- Change your code to use the filenames on the command line rather than the hard-coded names.